# TimeCategory add minutes using vars

Tags: groovy

How do i add minutes to currentDate.
I might add  more than 1440 minutes..

```
def AddMinutes = 1445
currentDate  = new Date();
println currentDate
use( TimeCategory ) {
  NewCurrentDate = currentDate + AddMinutes.minutes // fails
  NewCurrentDate = currentDate + 1445.minutes // works
}
println currentDate

Tue Feb 23 15:09:13 CET 2016
Wed Feb 24 15:14:13 CET 2016
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me...  Can't see your problem apart from you're not printing out the `newCurrentDate` (PS:  Lower case letters for variable names, otherwise Groovy can get confused, and think you're on about classes -- but that's not the issue here)

```
import groovy.time.*

def addMinutes = 1445

currentDate  = new Date()

use( TimeCategory ) {
  newCurrentDate = currentDate + addMinutes.minutes
}

println currentDate    //Tue Feb 23 14:45:52 GMT 2016
println newCurrentDate //Wed Feb 24 14:50:52 GMT 2016
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I needed to make sure that the `addMinutes` was an `int`. So I added this before in my script:

```
addMinutes = addMinutes.toInteger()
```

and now it works.